# when the name that used for pull up and pull down be deleted, how to fix?

Tags: mysql, pull

## In the condition that

user pulls down the data list from server by the param KEY, first pull down data like this:

```
KEY,        TITLE,      CONTENT
----------

sdfagwerag, title01,    content01

ajgjiwrgjw, title02,    content02

jagjssdjws, title03,    content03

sdfwrgjfew, title04,    content04

dfsdfwrgjw, title05,    content05
```

- and, admin delete the item(dfsdfwrgjw,title05,content05)
- user pulls down the data again, now param KEY is dfsdfwrgjw which has been deleted. so , I dont have the KEY to query in MYSQL and can not query the data like (before KEY ... or after KEY)

how could fix this problem???

Comment: If the data has been deleted, then obviously you cannot any more  provide that data. That typically is exactly _why_ data is deleted: to _not_ provide it any more. So it is unclear what you actually ask... Imagine 3 people inside a room: Joe, Jane and Jack. Now Jack leaves the room. After that you call out loud "would Jack please raise his arm" into the room and expect an arm to go up? How that?

Comment: sorry,,I want to know how to fix the problem. That Clients query data by the **KEY** like this: first,,`select createdtime from table where key = KEY` ,,second,,`select * from date<createdtime limit 10`.....but someone delete the **item** of the **KEY** at this time...so , in the first step,,would raise an error...so how could I pull down the data in a right way??@arkascha

Comment: Sorry. once more: if the data has been deleted, then there is no way to query it any more. Why do you think otherwise? This either does not make any sense at all or I really miss your point here.

Comment: Or could it be that those two queries done by the client actually depend on each other? One fetching some data that is then used inside the second query? _Then why don't you say so?_ In that case you should consider using a `JOIN`, so that you have only a single query.

Comment: like this [https://www.reddit.com/dev/api](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api),,,the **API** use **before** and **after** with a **fullname** param to query data...I want to know when  the **fullname** which client already cache in local was deleted in server...the client still use this **fullname** to query...but server has no way to find this **fullname** ..and how **Reddit** make sure to query the right data(after or before) with the empty **fullname** ??

Comment: I did not read through all of that, but the most likely step you have to understand is that in database applications when something is "deleted" it is often not really physically deleted in the database but only "marked as deleted". So actually it still exists and can be referenced. This has several advantages: you can "undelete things again" and you do not lose your referencial integrity.

Comment: thanks, this point undelete things again helps me a lot, Im going to try a bit.